# Performing Segue Programmatically from CollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, xcode8

I currently have created a Collection View within a Collection View Cell. **A Collection View within a Collection View.** I am having trouble performing a segue or presenting a View Controller on `didSelectItemAt` within the Second View Controller. Right now everything I have tried results in a crash or I get the "view not in view hierarchy" error.

Here is a picture to explain:

[image]

Here is my Code:

**Collection View 1:**

```
class ExploreVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


var businessView: UIViewController!

let foodCategory = exploreCategory()
let shopCategory = exploreCategory()
let cultureCategory = exploreCategory()
let nightlifeCategory = exploreCategory()

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!



override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    collectionView.register(categoryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "category")

    exploreCategories = exploreCategory.setCategories()
    businessView = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "businessPage")

}




 func setCategories() -> [exploreCategory]{


    foodCategory.name = "Good Food"


    shopCategory.name = "Shopping Near You"


    cultureCategory.name = "Cultural Highlights"


    nightlifeCategory.name = "Start Your Night"



    return [foodCategory,shopCategory,cultureCategory,nightlifeCategory]
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { 

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "category", for: indexPath) as! categoryCell
    cell.exploreCategory = exploreCategories?[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let count =  exploreCategories?.count {

        return count
    }

    return 0 
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 280)

    return size
}

func gotToBusinessPage() {


    print("gotToBusinessPage is being executed")
    let top: UIViewController? = 
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    let businessPage = BusinessVC()
    top?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toBusiness", sender: self)
    //top?.present(businessPage, animated: true) { _ in }

    //present(businessPage, animated: true)

}
```

**Collection View 1 Cell:**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AlgoliaSearch
import SwiftyJSON
import AFNetworking

class categoryCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

private let cellId = "exploreCell"

//* MARK Algolia
var exploreSearch = [exploreBusiness]()
var businessIndex: AlgoliaSearch.Index!
let query = Query()
var searchId = 0
var displayedSearchId = -1
var loadedPage: UInt = 0
var nbPages: UInt = 0


//*MARK Set Cell Values
var exploreCategory: exploreCategory? {

    didSet {

        if let name = exploreCategory?.name {

            categoryLabel.text = name.uppercased()


        }

    }

}


//*MARK Init
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setUpViews()
    searchFood(category: (exploreCategories?[0])!)
    searchShop(category: (exploreCategories?[1])!)
    searchCulture(category: (exploreCategories?[2])!)
    searchNightlife(category: (exploreCategories?[3])!)
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


//*MARK UI Mark Up
let categoryLabel: UILabel = {

    let black = UIColor(red:0.29, green:0.29, blue:0.29, alpha:1.0)
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 14)
    label.textColor = black
    label.text = "TRENDING NEAR YOU"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.numberOfLines = 1

    return label

}()

let businessCollectionView: UICollectionView = {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return collectionView

}()



//* MARK UI Set Up
func setUpViews(){


    addSubview(businessCollectionView)
    addSubview(categoryLabel)

    businessCollectionView.dataSource = self
    businessCollectionView.delegate = self
    businessCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false


    businessCollectionView.register(exploreCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)


    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": categoryLabel]))

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": businessCollectionView]))

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[categoryLabel(24)][v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": businessCollectionView, "categoryLabel": categoryLabel]))

}



//*MARK CollectionView Set Up

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let count = exploreCategory?.businesses?.count {

        return count

    }

    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! exploreCell
    cell.business = exploreCategory?.businesses?[indexPath.item]


    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let size = CGSize(width: 124, height: frame.height - 30)

    return size
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 16, 0, 16)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! exploreCell
    cell.business = exploreCategory?.businesses?[indexPath.item]


    let cellData = cell.business
    businessName = (cellData?.businessName!)!
    businessID = (cellData?.objectID!)!
    businessType = (cellData?.businessType!)!
    zipcode = (cellData?.zipcode!)!
    state = (cellData?.state!)!
    address = (cellData?.address!)!
    city = (cellData?.city!)!
    hours = "\(cellData?.openTime! ?? "error") - \(cellData?.closeTime! ?? "error")"
    if cellData?.image1URL?.isEmpty == false {

        image1 = (cellData?.image1URL!)!
        images.append(image1)

    }

    if cellData?.image2URL?.isEmpty == false {

        image2 = (cellData?.image2URL!)!
        images.append(image2)
    }

    if cellData?.image3URL?.isEmpty == false {

        image3 = (cellData?.image3URL!)!
        images.append(image3)
    }

    if cellData?.image4URL?.isEmpty == false {

        image4 = (cellData?.image4URL!)!
        images.append(image4)
    }

    if cellData?.image5URL?.isEmpty == false {

        image5 = (cellData?.image5URL!)!
        images.append(image5)
    }

    if cellData?.image6URL?.isEmpty == false {

        image6 = (cellData?.image6URL!)!
        images.append(image6)
    }

    if cellData?.image7URL?.isEmpty == false {

        image7 = (cellData?.image7URL!)!
        images.append(image7)
    }



    let tab = ExploreVC()

    tab.gotToBusinessPage()



    }
}
```

**2nd Collection View Cell:**

```
import UIKit
import AlamofireImage
import Alamofire

class exploreCell: UICollectionViewCell {

weak var exploreVC : ExploreVC?
var mainVC = ExploreVC()

var business: exploreBusiness? {

    didSet {


        nameLabel.text = business?.businessName
        reviewLabel.text = "\(business?.reviewCount! ?? 0) Reviews"

        let url = URL(string: (business?.image1URL)!)
        Alamofire.request(url!).responseImage { response in


            if let image = response.result.value {

                self.imageView.image = image


            }
        }


     }

}



override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setUpViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

let imageView: UIImageView = {
let iv = UIImageView()

    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return iv

}()

let nameLabel: UILabel = {

    let black = UIColor(red:0.29, green:0.29, blue:0.29, alpha:1.0)
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Paradise Diner"
    label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 14)
    label.textColor = black
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    return label

}()

let reviewIcon: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "review-black")
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return iv

}()

let reviewLabel: UILabel = {

    let black = UIColor(red:0.29, green:0.29, blue:0.29, alpha:1.0)
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "45 Reviews"
    label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 14)
    label.textColor = black
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    return label

}()


func setUpViews(){

    addSubview(imageView)
    addSubview(nameLabel)
    addSubview(reviewIcon)
    addSubview(reviewLabel)

    let ImageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: 182)
    let nameLabelRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 190 , width: frame.width, height: 20)
    let reviewRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 220 , width: 16, height: 11)
    let reviewLabelRect = CGRect(x: 22, y: 217 , width: frame.width - 16, height: 16)



    imageView.frame = ImageRect
    nameLabel.frame = nameLabelRect
    reviewIcon.frame = reviewRect
    reviewLabel.frame = reviewLabelRect

    }

}
```

I'd be happy to explain more if this isn't clear.

Comment: The  CollectionView Delegate methods should be in controller `ExploreVC`, not in the cell.

Comment: There's a delegate method is in the cell, because it's a collection view within a collection view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is this line:

```
let tab = ExploreVC()
```

This is not asking your current ExploreVC to do it, instead its asking newly created instance to do it (which is why it fails).

What you have to do to fix this (without modifying your code too much) is:

1) Add a weak variable inside your "categoryCell" to reference your actual ExploreVC:

```
weak var exploreVC : ExploreVC?
```

2) Add a reference to it inside the "cellForItemAt" from your ExploreVC:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "category", for: indexPath) as! categoryCell
cell.exploreCategory = exploreCategories?[indexPath.item]
cell.exploreVC = self
return cell
```

3) Inside the didSelectItem function delete the "let tab = ExploreVC()" and add this instead:

```
exploreVC?.gotToBusinessPage()
```

Comment: I am trying to perform or present a view controller from the 2nd Collection View's cell. (The black cell)

Comment: Then just pass the reference to that one. The point is that you have to make your ExploreVC perform the segue, not a new instance as you seemed to be doing.

Comment: but how can I set it to self if it is in a categoryCell class? Or can I set it to self in there?

Comment: I figured it out! I made the weak var a global variable and set it to self in the viewDidLoad of ExploreVC